# localStorageを呼び出すタイミング

Tags: javascript, vue.js

#### 問題点

vue.jsで簡易アプリをしているのですが、localStorageを呼び出すタイミングが上手くいきません。

#### エラー箇所

下記のコードで、localStorageを呼び出しているつもりなのですが、データが消えてしまいます。

```
mounted: function() {
    this.items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) || [];
  },
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```
<div id="app">
    <ul v-for="item in items">
      <li>{{item.id}}</li>
    </ul>
    <p @click="addItem">
     クリックで追加
    </p>
 </div>
```

```
var vue = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
  data: {
      items:[
     {id:'a',text:'aaa'},
     {id:'b',text:'bbb'}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    addItem:function(){
     let todo = {id:'c', text:'ccc'}
      this.items.push(todo)
    }
  },
  watch: {
    items: {
      handler: function() {
        localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(this.items));
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) | [];
  },
})
```

#### 試したこと

mountedのタイミングが誤っていると考え、vue.jsのライフサイクルを各種試してみましたが、上手くいきませんでした。

#### URL

githubのURL
https://github.com/kondo97/demo.git

動作確認用のURL
https://kondo97.github.io/demo/

#### その他

お分かりになる方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授いただけると大変助かります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

#### 追記

本投稿はマルチポストとなっております。
https://teratail.com/questions/350335#reply-479899

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/350335) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorageにデータがない状態で以下を実行します

```js
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'))
=> null
```

nullと空配列のビット論理和を実行すると `0` になります

```js
null | []
=> 0
```

初期化で0をitemsに代入したためpushメソッドのコールでエラーとなっています

論理和（||）を利用すると期待通りになります

```js
this.items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) || [];
```

**追記**
修正後は一度ローカルストレージをクリアしてください(itemsが保存済みのため）
サイトを開いてディベロッパーツールのコンソールで `localStorage.clear()` を実行すればよいです

Comment: 空配列の指定が誤っていることが判明しました。itemsに初期値を入れておきたかったのですが、空配列を指定することで消えていたようです（当然ではありますが、、）。ローカルストレージを呼び出す際に、ローカルストレージに初期値を保存→呼び出しという手順を取りました。ご回答ありがとうございました。